# C++ version in .vcxproj files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcxproj

Is this possible to fetch project's standard of C++ language from .vcxproj files without opening Visual Studio and manually checking it?

Comment: .vcxproj is an XML file. So you can parse it yourself and look for the `LanguageStandard` tag. It will hold values like `stdcpp17`. However I don't think this format is formally documented in a way you can rely on. Why do you want to do it anyway ?

Comment: @wohlstad the `ClCompile` tag [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/cl-task?view=vs-2022), but that doesn't mention `LanguageStandard`

Comment: @Caleth found it browsing through the .vcxproj. I'm using VS2022. I wouldn't be surprised if they change it some time in the fufture.

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch"? Do you just want to read it in Notepad? Or do you want to use that information in a build script or otherwise automated script? If so, which language is the script written in?

Comment: @ThomasWeller i want to use this information to use it in my project on C#. Is there a way to do it? Cause LanguageStandard tag doesn`t always exist.

Comment: A [tag:c#] tag exists.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, is this a question regarding C#? I want to read .vcxproj file in C# and find version of C++ as it would by simple opening notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not add comment. So I post answer here.

In Visual Studio C++ project, LanguageStandard will not appear if the language standard has not been changed (Default C++14). After specifying the language explicitly and rebuilding the project, You will find LanguageStandard in the .vcxproj file.

There should be similar code samples in C#.Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Search the Label `<LanguageStandard>` in .vcxproj.

Simple test in C++:

```
fstream file;
file.open(path, ios::in );
if (!file.is_open())
{
    cout << -1 << endl;
    return;
}

string temp;
string result;
while (getline(file, temp))
{     
    istringstream ss(temp);
    while (ss >> result)
    {
        if(result.find("<LanguageStandard>") != std::string::npos) std::cout<<result<<std::endl;
    }
   
}
```

Use python for example:

```
f=open('FilePath')
lines=f.readlines()
for lines in lines:
    if  "<LanguageStandard>" in lines:
        print(lines)
```

Comment: This tag doesn`t always exist. For some projects it is in the file, but for some it isn`t. For example, i can find this tag in my Qt project developed in VS by using Qt tools. But for simple console applications i'm not able to find it.